# Saving multi-sheet excel file to Azure Blob Storage using Pandas in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to create two sheets in an excel file, and then upload it to Azure Blob Storage using Pandas in Python. However, I am getting an error - "Cannot .getvalue() of 'OpenpyxlWriter' object new_writer".

```
    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=new_container_name, blob=file_name)

    writer = io.BytesIO()

    summary = pd.DataFrame({"one_val": [1, 2]})
    summary.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet A", index=False)
    blob_client.upload_blob(writer.getvalue(), overwrite=True)

    writer = io.BytesIO()
    summary2 = pd.DataFrame({"two_val": [3, 4]})

    with pd.ExcelWriter(writer, engine="openpyxl", mode="a") as new_writer:
        summary2.to_excel(new_writer, sheet_name="Sheet B", index=False, encoding="utf-8")
        blob_client.upload_blob(new_writer.getvalue(), blob_type="AppendBlob", overwrite=False)
```

Any help regarding a solution to this problem is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: See my answer below, but I would guess, that you forgot ```writer.save()``` before ```writer.getValue()```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this for how to save xlsx to a string
https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#saving-the-dataframe-output-to-a-string

and this for handling multiple sheets
https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_multiple.html

final example is

```
import pandas as pd
import io

# Create some Pandas dataframes from some data.
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [11, 12, 13, 14]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [21, 22, 23, 24]})

output = io.BytesIO()

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')

# Write the data frame to the BytesIO object.
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet2')

writer.save()
xlsx_data = output.getvalue()
```

Comment: Hi, how the container name and blob name are defined for the excel file uploaded to azure in your example? thx!

Comment: You would have to use the Azure pyhton library. How to is here https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python?tabs=managed-identity%2Croles-azure-portal%2Csign-in-azure-cli#upload-blobs-to-a-container